# Windows 7 laptop license

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, license, desktop-computer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

I use Ubuntu almost exclusively. But, in order to buy the laptop I want, it's bound to come with Windows 7. I could always go the EULA refund route and try to get a refund for it.

But I was wondering if there was anyway I could transfer the license I bought via the laptop to a a desktop PC. I have desktop running XP right now that I wouldn't mind having windows 7 on.

Is there anyway I could transfer the windows 7 license from the laptop, install Ubuntu on it and install windows 7 on my desktop? I have no need for 7 on a laptop, as I won't be playing any games on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The license will more than likely be an OEM license that **has** to stay with the laptop. This is in the terms of the license and may well be enforced by use of a special key.

I'd go the refund route and then buy a retail copy of Windows 7 for the desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, the license that comes with a laptop is a special OEM license.  It's BIOS-locked to that particular manufacturer, and therefore not transferable in this manner.  (If you can specify the laptop model, we can confirm, as there are a few, especially boutique brands, that may differ.)